# Jenkins - How to Make Users only View Project Results? & not have the ability to Execute builds?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins - How to Make Users only View Project Results? & not have the ability to Execute builds?

1. I have created an admin account.
2. I have created a new user account (Should only have ability to view test results).
3. My setup uses the following matrix: 
   [image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with selenium / webdriver. Please remove those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a read only user You need to check only the following permissions:

**Overall:** Read
**Job:** Read

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJc37.png) is how the read only user will see the job's build screen.